# Does adding new action for the scene remove automatically the one before in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I want to know if I made a sequence action and while this sequence is running a new action added to the scene , Does the new action stop the sequence ?

If yes , how i can make both of them working if the new action is added in swift ?

Comment: Thank you. Does the same thing can be applicable on the view(not nodes) , like : self.run(SkAction.sequence[moveBy,WAIT,moveBy]) then while this happening new action like "self.addChild(node)" . I tried this code and what happened is the first moveBy action worked then the WAITING action worked then when the new action added while the WAITING action is working, the second moveBy did not work. I can not make them in group because there is no specific time for the new action to be added(it happened in special cases)

Comment: How many nodes are involved in this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time a new action will interfere with any running actions is if both actions share the same key.  If you do not assign a key, then every time you add an action, it gets added to the action pool and will run concurrently.

Answer (score 3):

If you just give it a try, I'm sure you'll find the answer yourself.

But anyway, I tried it for you:

```
node.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: 100, y: 0, duration: 3), SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 100, duration: 3)]))
node.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), duration: 6))
```

And what I see is that the node both moves and rotates. So each subsequent action you tell a node to run will be run simultenuously.

Another way to run actions at the same time is to use `SKAction.group`.

Answer (score 1):

I've follow your comment, seems you are in the situation of overlap of the actions.

When you have a node and you want to launch one or more action, especially a **sequence** of actions where your node are involved in movements, you should be sure that these actions are finished.

To do it, for example to self:

```
let seq = SKAction.sequence([action1,action2,..])
if self.action(forKey: "moveToRoof") == nil {
   self.run(seq, withKey:"moveToRoof")
}
```

You can also do:

```
let group1 = SKAction.group([action1, action2,..])
let group2 = SKAction.group([action1, action2,..])
let addNewNode = SKAction.run{
    self.addChild(node)
}
let seq = SKAction.sequence([action1, group1, action2, addNewNode, group2,..])
if self.action(forKey: "moveToGround") == nil {
       self.run(seq, withKey:"moveToGround")
}
```

In your case seems you want to add nodes to a node that following the position of his parent..

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if let child = myNode1, let parent = child.parent  { // if exist follow the parent position
            child.position = parent.position
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to make both of them work together  if the new action suddenly added.

Comment: Depend by what do you want to achieve, you are also be able to add more actions like add 1 node, another node also, and give to them their moves, you can also add group actions in a sequence action

Comment: The problem i do not know when the node adding action will happen so that i can put them in a sequence or group . Adding new action does not has specific way or time to be added(it happens randomly)

Comment: Yes when the new node added , I want it to follow the exactly moving of other nodes without stopping the second MoveBy action (because after WAIT action finished , I want all the nodes "the new and the old" to back to normal Moving speed)

Comment: You can intercept the "existing of these nodes" from the `update` methods, check if they exist and if they have a parent, so decide what to do..just only remember always to protect your code with conditions..

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find a way to solve my problem using update method.