# Uneven typing in Spritekit SKAction sequence led typing animation

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

Hi I know there are plenty of questions on here about the timer, but nothing I can find about this specific issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

I am trying to use a sequence of SKActions to simulate a typing animation (in an SKLabelNode I've called actualLabel) that begins after a user touch.

I have the following:

```
var charArray = []
var labelText = ""
var calls = 0
```

And then, in touchesEnded:

```
if calls < charArray.count + 1 {
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
    let block = SKAction.run({
                self.redoLabelText()
            })
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait,block])
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))
}
```

With my function as the following:

```
func redoLabelText() {
    if labelText.characters.count < charArray.count {
        labelText += charArray[calls]
        actualLabel.text = labelText
        calls += 1
    }
}
```

And then touchesBegan resets all the initial variables and the process starts again. Everything works fine, except the typing is really choppy. Every time the user presses again, the typing gets faster. It's as if after one press it works fine, then after two etc there are more characters waiting in labelText at each second interval.

Thanks again, got me baffled.

Comment: Seems an overlapping of actions. Try to take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41812885/1894067)  answer

Comment: Thankyou, perfect explanation hiding in another question!

Comment: i have a solution will post shortly . however, a proper aolution is only available in objC, short of you writing your own  CoreAnimations

Comment: Are you trying to do this for just one or two instances, or are you making some sort of dialogue based game and need extensive use of this effect? (changes how I answer)